# How to pass a bash variable into awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a variable that is created in bash, and want to use it within awk statement to create a file by concatenating it with a string for the filename.

```
awk -v value="${index}" 'BEGIN{}{print $9 >> "example_value.txt";}END{}'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What I want is to change value with index to create multiple files such as example_1.txt, example_2.txt, etc.

Comment: This question is very common.. Strange that these type of things cannot be googled :) There must be at least 100 similar questions..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use it outside of the double quotes. [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) concatenates it without any other character:

```
awk -v value="${index}" 'BEGIN{}{print $9 >> "example_" value ".txt";}END{}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `-v`option as in the examples previously posted.

Or you could just use something like :

```
awk 'BEGIN{}{print $9 >> "example_'"$index"'.txt";}END{}'
```

Moreover, you don't have to use `{}` around the variable `index` in this case.